# polkit-mate-authentication-agent won't start - "Error getting authority"

Tags: arch-linux, polkit

I am using Arch Linux on an x86_64 desktop. Since a recent full system update, it seems my polkit-mate-authentication-agent will not start. If I try to start it manually from the command line, I get the following error:

```
$ ./polkit-mate-authentication-agent-1 

(polkit-mate-authentication-agent-1:2709): polkit-mate-1-WARNING **: 19:55:48.909: Error getting authority: Error initializing authority: Error calling StartServiceByName for org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1: Launch helper exited with unknown return code 127
```

Does anyone know what the problem might be, or how I can diagnose it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I have figured out what the issue was with this. It seems that after the system update, `polkitd` wasn't being started on boot, which is obviously why the authentication agent wasn't able to connect. I re-installed the `polkit` package and now `polkitd` is starting correctly. (I have no idea what was causing it to not start previously though)

Answer (score 2):

Hard to say from the amount of information provided.  However, the `return code 127` indicates that the command was not found.

Run it with `strace` to see what is supposed to be executed and is missing.

Comment: Yes, the lack of information is part of the problem. The error message is short and doesn't seem very helpful. I navigated directly to the folder containing the executable, so that file is certainly there. I will try your suggestion and see if it can shed any light on things.

Comment: @Time4Tea the presence of executable does not mean anything.  It is important to verify that it is actually this exactable that gets executed.

Comment: I've figured out the problem. It seemed that for some reason `polkitd` wasn't getting started on boot, which is why the authentication agent wasn't starting. I will post my own answer to resolve the question. Thanks!

Comment: @Time4Tea so the reason was correct, it was not able to find `polkitd` thus the error `127` no found.